# Multiple notifications to the same activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent, notificationmanager

I have an activity that is being opened from the notification bar, but when I do `NotificationManager.notify(...)`, I'm giving to the intent a different bundle, so that each notification opens the same activity, but obtaining from the DB other information each other.

But when I try to enter to any of the notifications (for example there are 3 notifications), they all send me to the activity with the same bundle that the last one. After trying with some Flags, I really don't know where is the problem (some flags makes the notification enter to the activity with the first bundle).

I'm following the way they used it in [the tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Comment: Can you share some of the code where you are creating the Pending Intents? I had a similar issue and it was because they were the pending intents were being reused by the framework.

Answer (score 114):

If the PendingIntent has the same operation, action, data, categories, components, and flags it will be replaced.

Depending on the situation i usually solve this by providing a unique request code either as static values (0,1,2) or the row id of the data I'm receiving from the DB.

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, MY_UNIQUE_VALUE , notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Then I use the same unique value for notify() as

```
mNotificationManager.notify(MY_UNIQUE_VALUE, notification);
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this solutions works perfectly. I think the problem starts with the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) - that claims the request code is not being used currently, but it seems it is. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This did it for me. Many thanks. The developer docs indeed only mention a unique id for the notify method, not for the getActivity method.

Comment: PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT is not workng neither. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. But remember that MY_UNIQUE_VALUE must not be larger than 65535 (2^16) because only the first 16 bits of the request code are allowed to be used (2^8 for fragments). A simple solution is to use (MY_UNIQUE_VALUE % 65535) as requestCode. So it won't go beyond 2^16 ;)

Comment: Perfect Answer , Why isn't it the accepted answer until now?

Comment: i had same problem thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29981353/10751265 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/29258195/10751265