# How to Create Number of notifications in android Application?

Tags: android

Hai i want to create number  notification dynamically,i can able to create single notification only.Am searching and get answer in this forum [How to create Multiple statusbar Notifications in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224178/how-to-create-multiple-statusbar-notifications-in-android) but here the notification is mentiones.but i need dynamic multiple notification depend on number.

Suppose i have number=1 i need 1 notification,if number=2 i need 2 notification how to do this.kindly guide me?See my image if anybody dont understand my question kindly ask me?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add multiple number of notifications in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532748/how-to-add-multiple-number-of-notifications-in-android)

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry NoBody replies me So only i post again.Can you Guide me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link above shows how to send a notification:

`mNotificationManager.notify(id, notifyDetails);`

And set the id to be different each time, for instance if you want 5 notifications, you could try something like:

`for(int id = 0; id < 5; id++){mNotificationManager.notify(id, notifyDetails);}`

Comment: ya Thank you its working,Suppose i want to dispaly the Different message for different id

Comment: put: notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, intent); as well in the loop, and change the contentText each time.

Comment: you'll need some kind of algoritm. If (id == 0) contentText = "msg1" and so on