# send multiple intents from service to receiver

Tags: android, android-intent

I am making a simple app that generates notifications at 8 different times of the day.A service is generating the alarms using the alarm manager and I am using a broadcast receiver to catch the alarms and display the toast/create a notification.

the problem is that I am not able to create more than one alarm.The method I am using to create multiple alarms is a diffrent intent for each of them..but as soon as I launch the app on the emulator, all the messages get displayed simultaneously at a single time..
I dont know if it is the right method..
if it is, please help me to correct it
if not, please suggest some alternate way

I am attaching my code for service and receiver

```
package com.example.firstapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

private static final String tag = null;
int number = 0;
// MediaPlayer player;
String str, bread;
StringBuffer buf1, buf2, buf3, buf4, buf5, buf6, buf7, buf8;
Calendar time1, time2, time3, time4, time5, time6, time7, time8;
Bundle basket;;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i(tag, "service created");
    // player=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.song);
    // player.setLooping(false);
    try {
        createalarm();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void createalarm() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i1 = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    Intent i2 = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    Intent i3 = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    Intent i4 = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    Intent i5 = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    Intent i6 = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    Intent i7 = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    Intent i8 = new Intent(this, MyAlarmReceiver.class);

    fillbuffers();
    /*
     * fillbread(4); Bundle basket = new Bundle(); basket.putString("key",
     * bread); i.putExtras(basket);
     */
    PendingIntent pendingi1,pendingi2,pendingi3,pendingi4,pendingi5,pendingi6,pendingi7,pendingi8;

    time1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    time2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    time3 = Calendar.getInstance();
    time4 = Calendar.getInstance();
    time5 = Calendar.getInstance();
    time6 = Calendar.getInstance();
    time7 = Calendar.getInstance();
    time8 = Calendar.getInstance();

    time1.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    time1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
    time1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
    time1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    time1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    time2.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    time2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
    time2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 41);
    time2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    time2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    time3.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    time3.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
    time3.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 42);
    time3.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    time3.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    time4.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    time4.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
    time4.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 43);
    time4.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    time4.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    time5.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    time5.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
    time5.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 44);
    time5.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    time5.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    time6.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    time6.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
    time6.set(Calendar.MINUTE,45);
    time6.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    time6.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    time7.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    time7.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
    time7.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 46);
    time7.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    time7.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    time8.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    time8.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
    time8.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 47);
    time8.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    time8.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    // fillbread();
    //if (true) {
        fillbread(1);
        basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putString("key", bread);
        i1.putExtras(basket);
        pendingi1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time1.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingi1);

    //}
//if (System.currentTimeMillis() == time2.getTimeInMillis()) {
        fillbread(2);
        basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putString("key", bread);
        i2.putExtras(basket);
        pendingi2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i2,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time2.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingi2);

//  }
//   if (System.currentTimeMillis() == time3.getTimeInMillis()) {
        fillbread(3);
        basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putString("key", bread);
        i3.putExtras(basket);
        pendingi3 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i3,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time3.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingi3);

//  } 
//if (System.currentTimeMillis() == time4.getTimeInMillis()) {
        fillbread(4);
        basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putString("key", bread);
        i4.putExtras(basket);
        pendingi4 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i4,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                pendingi4);

//  }
    //else if (System.currentTimeMillis() == time5.getTimeInMillis()) {
        fillbread(5);
        basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putString("key", bread);
        i5.putExtras(basket);
        pendingi5 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i5,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                pendingi5);

//      }     else if (System.currentTimeMillis() == time6.getTimeInMillis()) {
        fillbread(6);
        basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putString("key", bread);
        i6.putExtras(basket);
        pendingi6 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i6,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                pendingi6);

//  } else if (System.currentTimeMillis() == time7.getTimeInMillis()) {
        fillbread(7);
        basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putString("key", bread);
        i7.putExtras(basket);
        pendingi7 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i7,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                pendingi7);

    //} else if (System.currentTimeMillis() == time8.getTimeInMillis()) {
        fillbread(8);
        basket = new Bundle();
        basket.putString("key", bread);
        i8.putExtras(basket);
        pendingi8 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i8,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                pendingi8);
//  }

}

private void fillbread(int number) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (number) {
    case 1:
        bread = buf1.toString();
        break;
    case 2:
        bread = buf2.toString();
        break;
    case 3:
        bread = buf3.toString();
        break;
    case 4:
        bread = buf4.toString();
        break;
    case 5:
        bread = buf5.toString();
        break;
    case 6:
        bread = buf6.toString();
        break;
    case 7:
        bread = buf7.toString();
        break;
    case 8:
        bread = buf8.toString();
        break;
    }
}

private void fillbuffers() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    buf1 = new StringBuffer();
    buf2 = new StringBuffer();
    buf3 = new StringBuffer();
    buf4 = new StringBuffer();
    buf5 = new StringBuffer();
    buf6 = new StringBuffer();
    buf7 = new StringBuffer();
    buf8 = new StringBuffer();

    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.yo);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    int index = 1, tcount = 0;
    String line;
    if (is != null) {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && tcount < 8) {
            switch (index) {
            case 1:
                buf1.append(line + "\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                buf2.append(line + "\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                buf3.append(line + "\n");
                break;
            case 4:
                buf4.append(line + "\n");
                break;
            case 5:
                buf5.append(line + "\n");
                break;
            case 6:
                buf6.append(line + "\n");
                break;
            case 7:
                buf7.append(line + "\n");
                break;
            case 8:
                buf8.append(line + "\n");
                break;
            }
            buf.append(line + "\n");
            tcount = tcount + 1;
            index = index + 1;
        }
    }
    // bread=buf1.toString();
    is.close();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "service destoryed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // player.stop();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Log.i(tag, "service started");
    // player.start();
}
```

}

Reciever code::

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle gotBasket = intent.getExtras();
    String msg = gotBasket.getString("key");
    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    NotificationManager nm =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Notification notify=new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_missed_call, msg, System.currentTimeMillis());
    Intent intent1= new Intent(context, DisplayMessage.class);
    Bundle basket = new Bundle();
    basket.putString("msg", msg);
    intent1.putExtras(basket);
    PendingIntent pending= PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent1, 0);
    notify.setLatestEventInfo(context, msg, "just a greeting message for you", pending);

    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle("just a greeting message for you")
    .setContentText(msg)
    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame)
    .build();

    nm.notify(0, notify);
    /*
     * Intent ourIntent= new Intent(context, Menu.class);
     * context.startActivity(ourIntent); //startAcTivity(ourIntent);
     */
    /*
     * AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
     * builder.setMessage(msg); builder.setCancelable(false);
     * builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
     * {
     * 
     * @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { //
     * TODO Auto-generated method stub } }); AlertDialog alert=
     * builder.create(); alert.show();
     */
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is happening because you are using FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT flag

```
   pendingi1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Use FLAG_ONE_SHOT everywhere if you dont want the previous pendingIntent to be replaced.

```
   pendingi1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i1,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: no, its not working
as soon as I start the service from another activity, all the toasts come up at once.

Comment: i see that you have hard coded time to 4:40 pm, is the time on device more than that?

Comment: actually everytime i run the app, i make sure that all the time values are ahead of the emulator time

Comment: just to check instead of setting time, try something like time2.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000)

Comment: nope..it's not working...now, only the first message is displayed..
if i make the changes as: time1.setTimeInMillis=System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000
time2.setTimeInMillis=System.currentTimeMillis() + 120000....like this..only the first message is displayed...after that ..nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because you are using same notification id for all which is overlapping
 so use different Ids for all which is  nm.notify(0, notify);
replace 0 to 1,2,3...

for more visit  [How to create Multiple statusbar Notifications in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224178/how-to-create-multiple-statusbar-notifications-in-android)