# I decided to press on the notification and open an activity where the full notification is shown

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

Since the message was not fully displayed on android, I decided to press on the notification and open an activity where the full notification is shown plz send full code

Comment: Maybe you put some code and tell us where you have a problem ? For sure sb help u faster then now. And give more details... what notification push or invoked by you? What message which you get in intent or maybe you invoke some activity and download full message from internet?

Comment: i m sending notification by Parse.com but when i press on notification then it not display can u help me ...

Comment: If u get notification on your phone, it means that server side works ok. The problem lays in your app, so as I said before show your code, where you get intent from parse ( propably BroadcastReceiver), where you create your notification code as well. We are not wizards, we can't help you without code. Too many things can be done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the full notification message via an intent to the activity where you want to display the message.

[How to create Multiple statusbar Notifications in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224178/how-to-create-multiple-statusbar-notifications-in-android)