# Android Multiple Notifications and with multiple intents

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I have a fairly simple app that takes the input from a user and then sets it as a notification. The user can create as many notifications as he/she likes. I want the user to click the notification and get taken to a new activity called `ResultActivity`. `ResultActivity` in turn reads in the `putExtras` from the notifications intent and shows it to the user. The code below allows me to do almost everything I wanted, except anytime a notification is pressed, I receive the `putExtra` of the last created notification.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, i,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Resources res = ctx.getResources();
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.ic_launcher))
    .setTicker("Remember to " + text.getText())
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentTitle(text.getText());

// Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
String pass = text.getText().toString();

resultIntent.putExtra("title", pass);
resultIntent.putExtra("uid", i);

TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
// Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
// Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

new Uri.Builder().scheme("data").appendQueryParameter("text", "my text").build();
builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

Notification n = builder.build();
n.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
nm.notify(i++, n);
text.setText(null);
```

1. Open the application
2. Type in "One"
3. Hit ok
4. Notification is sent
5. Open the application
6. Type in "Two"
7. Hit ok
8. Notification is sent

Now you have two notifications. One that says "One" and one that says "Two". If you click on the notification "Two" it takes you to a screen that says "Two". Perfect!

If you click on the notification "One" it takes you to a screen that says "Two". BROKEN!

### ResultActivity.java

```
public class ResultActivity extends Activity {
    String title = null;
    TextView text;

    int i=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);



        title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
         i = getIntent().getIntExtra("uid", 0);


        text.setText(title);

    }
```

Comment: Please do not repost questions, even if you delete the old one(s).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You create multiple intents that are mixed. I cleaned up the code (but did not test it)

```
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Resources res = ctx.getResources();

    // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
    String pass = text.getText().toString();
    resultIntent.setData(new Uri.Builder().scheme("data")
            .appendQueryParameter("text", "my text").build());
    resultIntent.putExtra("title", pass);
    resultIntent.putExtra("uid", i);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ResultActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,
                            R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setTicker("Remember to " + text.getText())
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(text.getText())
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    Notification n = builder.build();
    n.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    nm.notify(i++, n);

    text.setText(null);
```

Comment: I would like to do this the "proper" way. I just tried UPDATE_CURRENT, but I get the same problem.

Comment: I also tried adding `notificationIntent.setAction("ACTION_" + System.nanoTime);` but that didn't do the trick either.

Comment: The [proper way](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) is for one app to show one notification (look for "Stack your notifications"). If you have several notifications you should collect them into one. If you need to display multiple notifications anyway they should display different data. Thus, set your data in the data parameter not an extra.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed it up with your virtually identical questions that where I tried to help you...

Comment: Hmmm... so I've been using putExtra when I should be using putData? EDIT: I just noticed theres no such thing as putData. Care to clarify?

Comment: Okay, so I see the changes you have made, and your code works (without errors in eclipse), but it still has the same problem as before. Do you think my ResultActivity.java might be the problem? I upvoted your question because I believe you're on the right track. But there must be something that is not causing it to work properly. I also added in my ResultActivity.java in my question

Comment: Sorry, replace "my text" with pass

Comment: IT WORKED! This is awesome and exactly what I've been trying to do for such a long time. I really appreciate the help and your time!

Comment: One last thing actually. If I set the two notifications to have the same title the app gets a bit glitchy, as it won't clear the notification in the ResultActivity. Any idea why?

Comment: The title is more or less the id, add the "ACTION_" + System.currentTimeMillis() fix to the same intent as I set the data, and all intents will be unique. Or even better add a second parameter that you can call time to the intent (`resultIntent.setData(new Uri.Builder().scheme("data")
            .appendQueryParameter("text", "my text")..appendQueryParameter("time", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()).build());`)

Comment: What if i have to pass arraylist in ResultActivity using resultIntent.setData?

Answer (score 27):

I know this was a lot time ago but i feel that the answers have not said anything about the problem in your code.
So the problem is pretty much here
`PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

So you create a pendingIntent from the stackbuilder whith the flag of update_current. If you look at FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT it says

```
 /**
 * Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists,
 * then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new
 * Intent. For use with {@link #getActivity}, {@link #getBroadcast}, and
 * {@link #getService}. <p>This can be used if you are creating intents where only the
 * extras change, and don't care that any entities that received your
 * previous PendingIntent will be able to launch it with your new
 * extras even if they are not explicitly given to it.
 */
public static final int FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT = 1<<27;
```

So what happens in your use case is that you create two identical pendingintents from the stackbuilder and the second intent overrides the first one . Actually you never create a second you just update the extras of the first one.

So unfortunately there is no available flag for your use case , but there is a good hack around it. What you can do is use the setAction of your resultIntent and place a random string or a string that makes sense to your app.

eg. `resultIntent.setAction("dummy_action_" + notification.id);`

This will make your resultIntent unique enough , so that the pendingIntent will create it rather than updating a previous one.

Comment: only using PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT worked for me .. is this can create any other issue?

Comment: I lost a solid 4 hours to this. `resultIntent.setAction` solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: I lost more than 4 hours on that, I had no idea that was the issue I had all along, thanks so much for this WA!!!

Comment: When targeting API 29+, using `intent.setIdentifier()` would be cleaner: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setIdentifier(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 17):

Set different `requestCode` helps me create and update current intent.

```
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
  this,
  notificationID,
  intent,
  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
)
```

Comment: I don't know why people are not voting this answer up. If you use same request code than it will create only one pending intent and it will update every next time when you use same request code to create another one. I have tried this solution and it's working like a charm. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: Correct answer. Thanks

Comment: This now seems to be working for me. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Use some random requestCode to seperate two notifications

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, CommonTools.getRandomNumber(1, 100),
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

public int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
    // min (inclusive) and max (exclusive)
    Random r = new Random();
    return r.nextInt(max - min) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your pending request code to System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(). It worked.

```
val pendingNotificationIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        this,
        System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(),
        notificationIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
```