# Multiple notification on same intent

Tags: java, android

I am writing an application and in this application **I need to set multiple notification with same intent** just like open my application whenever user tap on any notification.

All the notification comes on different time and date without having any data but the problem is, **if I set two notification for 03:27 PM and 03:28 PM then the first notification (03:27 PM) is canceled (Overwritten by second) and second is working correctly**.

I am currently using this code for achieving this goal:

this method is used to set notification from Activity:

```
 public static void setNotificationOnDateTime(Context context, long fireTime)
     {
         int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

         AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
         Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);

         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestID, i, 0);
         am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fireTime, pi);
     }
```

and my NotificationReceiver class look like this:

```
 NotificationManager nm;

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.w("TAG", "Notification fired...");

     nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

     PendingIntent contentIntent;

     Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras().getBundle("NotificationBundle");
     if(bundle == null)
     {
         contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                 new Intent(context, SplashScreen.class), 0);
     }

     else
     {
         contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                 new Intent(context, MenuScreen.class)
         .putExtra("NotificationBundle", bundle), 0);
     }

     Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
             "Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());
     notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Me", "Message test", contentIntent);
     notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
     nm.notify(1, notif);
 }
```

I alerady spend a lot time on googling and found some solutions but they didn't work for me here is the link of some of them:

[android pending intent notification problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3009690/1250370)

[Multiple notifications to the same activity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6066363/1250370)

If any one knows how to do this please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quote](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29):

> Post a notification to be shown in the status bar. If a notification with the same id has already been posted by your application and has not yet been canceled, it will be replaced by the updated information.

But you're always using `1` for the `id` parameter. Use a unique ID when you post several notifications.

**Update** If that doesn't help, you can still create Intents which do not compare as being equal, while having an equal effect.

Comment: Thanks for your precious information, but how can I change notification id in NotificationReceiver class. onReceive called when receiver receive a notification. am I right?

Comment: @Pari You're basically already doing such a trick, although in a place where it's wasted: You generate a `requestID` which is, with a relatively high probability, unique, and pass it to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`, but according to the documentation, this is "currently not used". You can do the same trick for the `id` parameter of `notify()`. However, this makes only sense if you do not have to be able to identify the notifications based on their ID (in which case you'll need either consecutive IDs or a list of IDs you issued or something similar). But it will solve your problem.

Comment: @Pari I have also updated my answer with an additional suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

this may be helpful

notif.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

the notification will never close...

Comment: As you suggest, I set this flag and get two notification at the same time. I set two notification and get both notification at second notification time.

Comment: so that is your requirement? all r fine?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set as below :

> ```
>   contentIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(p_context, i, new Intent(context, MenuScreen.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
> ```

It might help you.