# Setting notification intent for multiple notifications

Tags: android

I have a method like this:

```
private void createNotification(String sender) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle(sender+" sent you a message")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ribony_top_icon)
        .setContentText("Touch for reply")
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("gcm_username",sender);
        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NotificationID.getID(sender), mBuilder.build());
}
```

I am creating 3 three notifications like this:

```
createNotification("test1");
createNotification("test2");
createNotification("test3");
```

Notifications are creating without any problem.But when I touch the notification `test1` or `test2` it is calling `test3` I mean all notification intents sets to last intent.How can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the PendingIntent has the same operation, action, data, categories,
>   components, and flags it will be replaced.
>
> Depending on the situation i usually solve this by providing a unique
>   request code either as static values (0,1,2) or the row id of the data
>   I'm receiving from the DB.

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, MY_UNIQUE_VALUE , notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

> Then I use the same unique value for notify() as

```
mNotificationManager.notify(MY_UNIQUE_VALUE, notification);
```

Answer:[Multiple notifications to the same activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066363/multiple-notifications-to-the-same-activity)

Answer (score 0):

This happends because when you create your PendingIntent, the last argument indicate if has some other pending intent to the same activity, just gonna be updated instead create a new one. You only need change the last argument to some of the other flags or only put 0 to indicate don't need a special flag.

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, 0);
```

**EDIT**

Add the message like a extra in the intent.

```
resultIntent.putExtra("message_extra", sender);
```

And in the Activity only recover the new extra to show the message.

Comment: now everything reverted.First intent is setting to all notifications.

Comment: Then you need pass the message in each intent like a extra and recover the message in the other side.

Comment: Can you explain more ?