# How to get different Push Notification for each task

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification

I have tried multiple solutions given by some sources, but that didn't work for me, below I given a dummy example,

[image]

I have same implementation like this, when multiple notification come that only increase count. I want separate notification for each task like this

[image]

this is my code for differentiate notification but that increasing count
here is some code

```
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, uiIntent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);



Notification notification = builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)    
                                  .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notificationIcon).SetTicker(message)
                                  .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.ic_action_accept, "Accept", null)
                                  .AddAction(Resource.Drawable.ic_action_remove, "Reject", null)
                                  .SetAutoCancel(true).SetContentTitle(title).SetNumber(DroidConstants.NotifyCounter)
                                  .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.All)
                                  .SetContentText(message).Build();
            notificationManager.Notify(unique++, notification);
```

please help me out on this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple notifications to the same activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066363/multiple-notifications-to-the-same-activity)

Comment: That solution is not worked for me, I already mention in one line code

Comment: Please show the code where you create your `notification` object and the pending `Intent`. I assume the issue is in the flags you are setting.

Comment: If your `PendingIntent` matches your unique value it should, you only setting the `Notify` using a unique id via `unique++`, thus the notifications will group.

Comment: hi @hvaughan3 I have updated some code, please check it.